# Powershell Set Permissions on home directory

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl

I am trying to use powershell to create home directories for users as well as set permissions for them accordingly.

I appear to keep running into this issue where I am unable to set the permissions. I am getting this error:

> Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $permissions.AddAccessRule($userpermissions)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException

Here is the section of code:

```
$UserDir = [string]::Format("{0}\{1}", $HomeDirRoot, $user["UserName"]) 
$Account = [string]::Format("{0}\{1}", "Domain", $user["UserName"])

#Create Directory
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $UserDir |Out-Null

# assign file permissions 

$FileSystemAccessRights=[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl"
$InheritanceFlags=[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::"ContainerInherit", "ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags=[System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$AccessControl=[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow

$NewAccessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ` ($Account, $FileSystemAccessRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControl) 
$CurrentACL=Get-ACL -path $UserDir
$CurrentACL.SetAccessRule($NewAccessrule)
Set-ACL -path $UserDir -AclObject $CurrentACL
```

I have tried several variations of this code and still end up with the same error. I have even got as far as simply getting the ACL object and then using it to set the permissions like below:

```
$folder = "\\fs\home\SAMACCOUNTNAMEHERE"
$permissions = Get-Acl $folder
Set-Acl $folder $permissions
```

I am at a loss here. Because the code works on folders on my machine but when i try to run it on a folder like above it blows up with the error relating to identity references.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You code above works fine, the error you are getting is down to the username you are giving. This error means that the username is not being recognized by active directory or your local machine. So check if your `$account` variable is producing what you think it is and that the account is present in active directory or the local machine.

```
$Account | Write-Host
```

Comment: I have tried that. I have even hard coded the account variable. Any ideas what might cause a user to not be recognized? Would running this code on a different machine (from where the folder exists) make a difference?

Comment: @NLarkin Is the account your connecting to a local account or in AD? And is the machine joined to the domain? Also have you tried using `Invoke-Command` to run the command remotely on the machine?